# How to create a bode plot for transfer function with square root?

Tags: matlab, control-theory

How to create a bode plot of this transfer function$ \frac{{1-e^{\sqrt{s}}}}{\sqrt{s}+e^{\sqrt{s}}}$(1)?

I tried using the transfer function to state space"tf2ss" from Matlab on (1) but that didn't work since the transfer function 's' doesn't work for transfer function with square roots.

Comment: How did you get such a TF? I would guess that there is no finite-dimension state-space representation for this system. However, you do not need a state-space model to create the frequency response.

Comment: You can also [plot it manually](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+20*log10%28abs%28%281-exp%28sqrt%28i*10%5Ex%29%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28i*10%5Ex%29%2Bexp%28sqrt%28i*10%5Ex%29%29%29%29%29+with+-6%3Cx%3C6), or do you need a state space model (approximation) for something else as well?

Comment: I already approximated that function, but I need to compare it to the exact  function which is (1) and I am having a hard time trying to figure it out. I will try to plot it manually and see if that helps. Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it.